# What is GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute(used for Target Name in .csproj file)?

Tags: c#, target, csproj

I have set code analysis rule in my project. So while compile time it will give me error if I have write code against rule.
The challenge is while build the project it gives me error from `.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.cs(..\AppData\Local\Temp)`.

To overcome this error i have set Target Name as **`GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute`** in `.csproj` file, it works but still i am confused about `GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute`. So, what is `GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute` and how it overcome compile time errors?

Comment: If you're still seeing this problem, please open an issue at https://github.com/dotnet/project-system